# Use JSON in Java

Tags: java, json, swing, jframe, actionlistener

I'm a beginner. I want to write a weather app that gets some information from the web and show it to the user. But I have trouble to pass the user input to the JSON method. Can anybody help me? 
the problem is in ActionListener part.

```
import com.google.gson.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.imageio.*;

public class Weather extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    static JButton getWeather;
    static JTextField inputZip, showCity, showState, showCondition, showTemp;
    static JLabel enterZip, city, state, condition, temp, image;
    public static double temp_f, temp_c;
    static Image pic;
    public static String zip, jCity, jState, jCondition, fORc;

    public Weather() throws Exception {
       //Button
        getWeather = new JButton("Get Weather");
        getWeather.addActionListener(this);
        //TextFiels
        inputZip = new JTextField(10);
        showCity = new JTextField(10);
        showState = new JTextField(10);
        showCondition = new JTextField(10);
        showTemp = new JTextField(10);
        //Labels
        enterZip = new JLabel ("Enter Zipcode:");
        city = new JLabel ("City:");
        state = new JLabel ("State:");
        condition = new JLabel ("Condition:");
        temp = new JLabel ("temp:");
        //Radio Buttons
        CheckboxGroup tUnit = new CheckboxGroup();
        Checkbox f = new Checkbox ("f", tUnit, true);
        Checkbox c = new Checkbox ("c", tUnit, false);
        //Image
        URL coldPicURL = new URL("https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/xmas-color/512/snow_snowflake_winter_cold_weather-128.png");
        URL hotPicURL = new URL("http://yowindow.com/img/yo_128.png");
        URL picURL = new URL ("http://findicons.com/files/icons/2796/metro_uinvert_dock/128/the_weather_channel.png");
        if (temp_f!=0 && temp_f<=60)
            pic = ImageIO.read(coldPicURL);
        else if (temp_f > 60)
            pic = ImageIO.read(hotPicURL);
        else 
            pic = ImageIO.read(picURL);  
        image = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(pic));
        //Frame
        JFrame weather = new JFrame ("Weather App");
        weather.setVisible(true);
        weather.setSize(500,250);
        weather.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Panels
        JPanel pInput = new JPanel();
        JPanel pDisplay = new JPanel();
        JPanel pDisplayInfo = new JPanel();
        JPanel pTempUnits = new JPanel();
        JPanel pImage = new JPanel();
        //Panels' Layout
        pInput.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        pDisplay.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        pDisplayInfo.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,2));
        pTempUnits.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        //Frame Layout
        weather.add(pInput, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        weather.add(pDisplay, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pDisplay.add(pDisplayInfo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        pDisplay.add(pTempUnits, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        weather.add(pImage, BorderLayout.EAST);
        //Insertion the objects into the panels
        pInput.add(enterZip);
        pInput.add(inputZip);
        pInput.add(getWeather);
        pDisplayInfo.add(city);
        pDisplayInfo.add(showCity);
        pDisplayInfo.add(state);
        pDisplayInfo.add(showState);
        pDisplayInfo.add(condition);
        pDisplayInfo.add(showCondition);
        pDisplayInfo.add(temp);
        pDisplayInfo.add(showTemp);
        pTempUnits.add(c);
        pTempUnits.add(f);
        pImage.add(image);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        zip = Weather.inputZip.getText();
        //HERE'S WHERE I'M STUCKED !!! :(
        getJson (zip);
        showCity.setText(jCity);
        showState.setText(jState);
        showCondition.setText(jCondition);
        if (fORc.equals("f"))
        showTemp.setText(Double.toString(temp_f));
        if (fORc.equals("c"))
        showTemp.setText(Double.toString(temp_c));
    }

    public static void getJson(String zip) throws Exception  {
        String json="", line;
        JsonElement jse;
        final String key = "7b86aadc43344a90";
        JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
        URL url = new URL("http://api.wunderground.com/api/" +
            key + "/conditions/q/" + zip + ".json");
        InputStream is = url.openStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
            json += line;
        rd.close();
        jse = parser.parse(json);
jCity=jse.getAsJsonObject().get("current_observation").getAsJsonObject().get("display_location").getAsJsonObject().get("city").getAsString();
        jState=jse.getAsJsonObject().get("current_observation").getAsJsonObject().get("display_location").getAsJsonObject().get("state").getAsString();
    jCondition=jse.getAsJsonObject().get("current_observation").getAsJsonObject().get("weather").getAsString();
        temp_f=jse.getAsJsonObject().get("current_observation").getAsJsonObject().get("temp_f").getAsDouble();
        temp_c=jse.getAsJsonObject().get("current_observation").getAsJsonObject().get("temp_c").getAsDouble();
    }   

    public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent ie){
        Checkbox cb = (Checkbox)ie.getItemSelectable();
        fORc = cb.getLabel();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Weather w = new Weather();
    }
}
```

Comment: what about using Gson

Comment: 1) *"Can anybody help me?"* [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) 2) *"the problem is in ActionListener part"* What is the result of the code statements? What did you expect the result to be? We are going to need a lot more detail in order to offer help.

Comment: I expected the ActionListener to get the zip from the textField and feed it to the getJson (zip) and show the results! but it does not!

Comment: the error is: "unreported exception java.lang.Exception; must be caught or declared to be thrown"

Comment: when I throw an exception the other error appears: "actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in Weather cannot implement actionPerformed (java.awt.event.ActionEvent) in java.awt.event.ActionListener overridden method does not throw java.lang.Exception"

Answer (score 0):

On a first level:

```
getJson (zip);
```

that call throws an **exception**. And in Java you have to either try/catch that exception; or add it to the signature of the method this happens (using the throws keyword). In your case, that is not possible, as you are actually overriding an existing method; and then you can't **add** a throws statement to the method signature.

But the real answer here is: **slow** down. The above compiler error is about a **super basic** thing within Java. When you don't know what an Exception is, and how to properly deal with that, then you are many hours of **learning** away from writing a Swing UI application that wants to deal with JSON data from a remote site.

This also becomes obvious when looking in how you structure your code. You clearly separate responsibilities; you create classes around those that help you coming up with a clean OO based model. For example, you would **fully** separate the UI layer (swing) that displays information from the specifics where such information is coming from. Your JFrame shouldn't know **anything** about JSON input.

Your code shows nothing of that. I call this the "you should learn to crawl before going for hurdle racing" syndrome.

Answer (score -2):

First,I think you'd better provide more detail information, what kind of problem is? Is that kind of exception for an unexpected result? Or you can just post the result for others to take a look.

Second, I tried to run your program. There are two issue in that.
1. in the code that you wrote a comment : //HERE'S WHERE I'M STUCKED !!! :(

```
zip = Weather.inputZip.getText();
    //HERE'S WHERE I'M STUCKED !!! :(
    getJson (zip);
    showCity.setText(jCity);
    showState.setText(jState);
```

the method getJson() you have "throws Exception", so when you invoke the method, you also need to deal with the exception maybe you can just catch the exception like this:

```
        zip = Weather.inputZip.getText();
    //HERE'S WHERE I'M STUCKED !!! :(
    try {
        getJson (zip);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    showCity.setText(jCity);
    showState.setText(jState);
```

Or you can continue throw the exception.

2. when finished the previous problem, I found the "fORc" will meet a null pointer exception which you need to check your process when to pass the var.

Third,still about the fORc, in your code, you wrote

```
if (fORc.equals("f"))
        showTemp.setText(Double.toString(temp_f));
if (fORc.equals("c"))
        showTemp.setText(Double.toString(temp_c));
```

But I suggest you can change like this, then you can deal when the fORc is a null:

```
    if (null == fORc)
        //do something. like throw exception
    if ("f".equals(fORc))
        showTemp.setText(Double.toString(temp_f));
    if ("c".equals(fORc))
        showTemp.setText(Double.toString(temp_c));
```

Hope could help you.

Comment: Thanks. the first part got fixed. I didn't know about printStackTrace(). The second part needs more work. Thank you though.

Comment: printStackTrace(). is just show a simple way. you can also logging or do other process. the point is you need to catch the exception.  By the way.. why I got "-2 vote"...